# Can you require an employer to give you a minimal period contract?

Tags: employment, career

If you decide to switch job, can you require an employer to guarantee that you will be able to work for them for 1 year at least without being able to get fired after a trial period? I am asking, because when changing job after getting several significant raises in a company, you might want to get some insurance you will keep earning a similar wage. How do you insure that?

Comment: Labor laws differ from one place to another. What place are you asking about?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a good topic for this site. It relies on labor laws for the country/state. It might make more sense on https://law.stackexchange.com/ or https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can try.  But good luck finding *any* employer who will agree to it, unless you're applying for a very senior management role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SInce labo(u)r laws differ significantly depending on the country, this is the situation in Slovakia: yes, you can demand a fixed term work contract (*zmluva na dobu určitú*), BUT this means the contract will automatically terminate unless prolonged - and the employer can still fire you in between. So this is in  fact something opposite from what you want.

However, what you can do  is to ask for a bigger compensation - usually two month wages, but (especialy if the unions are strong or the employer generous) it can be much longer - e.g. seven months (source: personal experience). But note that if the employer is dissatisfied with your performance, you can always be reassigned to a different position (though comparable, unless there is a reorganization and no comparable position remains), perhaps in a different city - and this is often used to "persuade" the employee to quit voluntarily.

But also note that if you just state during your job interview that you require bigger compensation, you'd better be *very good* and have an adequate reputation.

Comment: The first paragraph seems entirely irrelevant by your own admission, and asking for a higher salary just seems like a way to not get hired in the first place.